# Ubuntu Multipass mount command not working

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, macos

Recently I installed multipass on my mac. I've been trying to mount my home directory to my ubuntu VM. When I mount my home directory with   `multipass mount $HOME test` it works perfectly and the command `multipass info test` shows it's mounted.

```
Mounts:         /Users/mac => /Users/mac
                    UID map: 501:default
                    GID map: 20:default
```

But when I enter the VM's shell and type ls, I am only prompted with snap directory. I've looked everywhere but nobody has an answer. What can I do to use my home directory in a multipass VM?

Sorry for my English, it's my second language :)

Answer (score 2):

The directory is mounted in the VM as `/Users/mac`

If you wan't to mount it as your home directory (which you really should not do as it will probably break things) try:

```
multipass mount $HOME test:/home/YOURUSERNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

The default login for `multipass shell` is the user `ubuntu` with home directory `/home/ubuntu`.  Try this instead:

```
multipass mount $HOME test:/home/ubuntu/Mac
```

Now when you jump into the multipass shell, you should see the Mac directory.